# Push notification rules questions

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification

I've just learned the hard way to read Apple's guidelines before spending months on an app.  My app is a messaging app that sends push notifications to users who have subscribed to a given channel.  It requires push notifications to be enabled, and therefore it violates rule 5.3.

First question:  I have read the discussion at http://bit.ly/1n26GO6, but I'm not clear on my options.  If users refuse to get push notifications, what options do I have for getting the message to them?  I'm using Parse to send messages to channels.

Second question:  Rule 5.7 says "Apps cannot charge users for use of Push Notifications."  Clearly I can't charge people for **receiving** a push notification.  But can I charge users for the privilege of **sending** such notifications?

Thank you,

Eli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Push Notification should not deliver anything, and it shoudln't be a required/mandatory option, **ever**. It's a "luxury" that lets you know something happened, **nothing more**. Whatever you put in the payload that is mandatory for the app to function properly is a mistake. Push notifications aren't even guaranteed to be sent/received, it's a "best effort" service. ([here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html))

> Delivery of remote notifications is best-effort with a high success rate but is not guaranteed. For more on the payload, see The Remote Notification Payload.

Your users should receive the messages wether or not they registered to your notification service.

And I strongly suggest you do not make them pay for such service. It's pretty much free for the first 100.000.000 push everywhere you go. Parse is one of them. Note that no other app in the world asks for money for notifications only.

I'll say it again :

Your system should allow the users to send and receive messages without the notification. The notification will just warn them in case the app is closed.

Note you can also use silent notifications (same system but the user doesn't see it) to wake up the app and download data or update stuff accordingly.

Just remember this : notifications aren't a way to transfer data or call other devices. At best you use it to wake the app up in certain cases, and THEN start downloading services.

Make sure to take a few weeks to get your head around all that before starting the actual implementation, because you seem a little confused. If you're alone, it's pretty challenging at first. Even if learning the hard way and starting everything is a good way to learn, it's pretty frustrating. Take your time.

Comment: You're right, I am confused, and I appreciate your wise answer.  So how does the Weather app deliver thunderstorm warnings?  Isn't that an example of a push notification calling a device?  (I realize that this usage of a push notification is allowed because the information is already available elsewhere and the push is just a "luxury.")  But even so, isn't that push notification calling all devices that are subscribed to a given postal code?